# How to reuse the following codes without macro?

Tags: c

(C lang)
I have the following two functions to compare strings , like memcmp.
Using uint8_t[] and uint16_t[] to store different strings(8 bit strings and wide strings).

```
static int memcmp16_8(const uint16_t *s1, const uint8_t *s2, int len)
{
    int c, i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = s1[i] - s2[i];
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static int memcmp16(const uint16_t *s1, const uint16_t *s2, int len)
{
    int c, i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = s1[i] - s2[i];
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The same code looks bad.
But I don't know how to reuse codes without macro.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Are you sure `memcmp` doesn't fit your needs? (Or `strcmp`?) It's probably more understandable.

Comment: You could make a version using void * and pass in the stride length, then cast the s1 and s2 to the appropriate types before dereference.  Usually, memcpy is a highly optimized function where performance is way more important than a little code duplication.

Comment: If you wanted to merge the code, you'd need a 4th parameter to specify the datatype of the 2nd parameter. Is it big? Or is it small?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic between `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` differs by a factor of `2`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. (and likely prevent close and down votes)

Comment: If your intent is to return a negative value when s1 < s2, positive when s1 > s2 or else zero, your expression is not a portable way of doing that.

Comment: What kind of macro are you trying to avoid? Not all macros are evil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the different code into separate functions, and pass that to the general function as a parameter. It would look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*cmpxy_func)(const void *s1, const void *s2, const int i);

static int cmp16_8(const void *s1, const void *s2, const int i) {
    const uint16_t *ss1 = (uint16_t *)s1;
    const uint8_t *ss2 = (uint8_t *)s2;

    return ss1[i] - ss2[i];
}

static int cmp16_16(const void *s1, const void *s2, const int i) {
    const uint16_t *ss1 = (uint16_t *)s1;
    const uint16_t *ss2 = (uint16_t *)s2;

    return ss1[i] - ss2[i];
}

static int memcmpxy(
    const void *s1,
    const void *s2,
    const size_t len,
    cmpxy_func cmpxy
) {
    int c, i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = cmpxy(s1, s2, i);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[]) {
    const uint16_t s1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    const uint8_t s2_8[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    const uint16_t s2_16[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    printf("cmp16_8: %d\n", memcmpxy(s1, s2_8, 4, cmp16_8));
    printf("cmp16_16: %d\n", memcmpxy(s1, s2_16, 4, cmp16_16));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Well spotted. Only concern is that the OP was hoping for _fewer_ functions, not more... `:-)` (Just a cheap shot... Nice solution, imo!) In fact, there's no reason to keep the loop in the dispatch, Both "helpers" could skip along their respective arrays, simply returning a result... (ie: a "wrapper")

Comment: Please refer to my (out of jealousy) edit to consider implementation that doesn't require the caller of `memcmpxy()` to choose&identify the correct "helper" function. The caller can just use `sizeof` to pass a parameter value of 1 or 2 (sizeof char v. sizeof short)...

Answer (score 1):

With a 4th parameter specifying the actual interpretation of s2's datatype...

```
static int memcmp16(const uint16_t *s1, const uint16_t *s2, size_t len, int s2Actual) {
    int rval = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    if( s2Actual == 2 ) {
        while( i < len && s1[i] == s2[i] ) i++;
        rval = i == len ? 0 : s1[i] - s2[i];
    } else { // else 1
        uint8_t *ss2 = (uint8_t *)s2; // downcasting s2 to a single byte pointer
        while( i < len && s1[i] == ss2[i] ) i++;
        rval = i == len ? 0 : s1[i] - ss2[i];
    }
    return rval;
}
```

**EDIT:**
How to distinguish first solution as slightly easier to scan & maintain.

Then the calling function could be quite easy to validate at a glance:

```
// param 3 - count of array elements
// param 4 - 1 for uint8_t, 2 for uint16_t
res = memcmp16( a1, a2, sizeof a1/sizeof a1[0], sizeof a2[0] );
```

Or, just making your code more compact...

```
static int memcmp16(const uint16_t *s1, const uint16_t *s2, size_t len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while( i < len && s1[i] == s2[i] ) i++;
    return i == len ? 0 : s1[i] - s2[i];
}

static int memcmp16_8(const uint16_t *s1, const uint8_t *s2, size_t len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while( i < len && s1[i] == s2[i] ) i++;
    return i == len ? 0 : s1[i] - s2[i];
}
```

Comment: Another option could be a mask and compare.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I thought about using a union, but the increment of the underlying array (and differencing) made things a bit complicated (imho)... They're all just bytes, but letting the compiler figure out the Endian problems just seems easy... Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Everything seems easy until you have to juggle between varying cases of input on the fly `:)`. I think this is as good as any way to approach it. My thought was a mask of low/high bite when needed, and a shift if the high-byte needed isolation. It does the same thing, but probably a little more cryptically for a new programmer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That "varying cases" is a good point! I'm too tired to do it, but... Forgetting the 'suffix' on the 'byte' version function name wouldn't raise the compiler's eyebrow, but would be a real bug... More visibility of the difference in the two func names would be a VG idea! `:-)` I wonder if "Cybran" has wandered off somewhere, never to return... `:)`

Comment: That's always a risk you run with new members here. I suspect he will be back, with the world divided into 24 timezones, it's hard to have everybody here at once. Some are weekday members as well. I know when I was under 30, you would have a hard time catching me doing anything work-related on the weekends `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Reusing code without a macro is achieved in a dialect of C called C++ using templates.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename left_char, typename right_char>
int compare(left_char *l, right_char *r, size_t n)
{
   if (n == 0)
     return 0;
     
   if (*r < *l)
     return -1;

   if (*r > *l)
     return 1;

   return compare(l + 1, r + 1, n - 1);     
}


int main()
{
   std::printf("%d\n", compare(L"abc", "abc", 3));
   std::printf("%d\n", compare("abc", L"abc", 3));
   std::printf("%d\n", compare("alpha", L"bravo", 5));
   std::printf("%d\n", compare(L"alpha", "bravo", 5));
   std::printf("%d\n", compare("bravo", L"alpha", 5));
   std::printf("%d\n", compare(L"bravo", "alpha", 5));
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
1
1
-1
-1
```

If you want to reuse code syntax for different types in C, you will have to resort to macros.

Starting in the C11 dialect of ISO C, there is something called `_Generic` to help with generic programming; however, macros will still be involved in order to hide it.

Comment: *a dialect of C called C++* ????  That will get you shot for heresy in some quarters!

Comment: Thanks. I can't use C++ here, but it still helps me.

Comment: "I can't use C++ here", where is that? On your 80286 PC/AT in Ruritania?  You cannot even build GCC without C++; it's written in C++ now, and the C++ compiler gets boostrapped before you can get the C front end.  That said, I don't advocate C++. But C++ has the solution if you want to write the same piece of code, without any preprocessor macros (or other techniques like external code generation), and have it work with different types.

Comment: This is not new, either; compilers from a quarter century ago could handle the above template function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe clearly. I'm adding some codes to a pure C project and don't want to break conventions.